# Moving partition from one disk to another

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have the `rog strix x570-e gaming` motherboard, which has 2 equal NVME M2.2 SSD slots.

Up till now, I had been using only a single M2.2 1TB SSD with a both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed. My 1 TB SSD was getting really full, so I purchased the same one again, and plugged it in my motherboard.

I would like to maintain a dual boot, but only have 1 OS on each SSD.
Therefore, I would like to either:

A) Move my existing Windows partition to the new SSD, and keep the Ubuntu one as it is, or

B) Move my existing Ubuntu partition to the new SSD, and keep the Windows one as it is

I am unable to move partitions across drives easily so far, and I ideally don't want to have to *reinstall* a new OS altogether, rather simply moves my files onto the new disk's formatted filespace (NTSF or Ext/ExFAT depending on whether I chose option A or B).

Which option would be easier, and how can I do it ? I have the following partitions (removed all the snap loops):

```
eklavya@eklalinux:/$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/eklavya/UbuntuDisk
nvme1n1     259:2    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:3    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:4    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:5    0 735.6G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p4 259:6    0   505M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p5 259:7    0 195.3G  0 part /
└─nvme1n1p6 259:8    0    33M  0 part
```

(For now I formatted the new disk into `Ext4` Linux FileSystem, and called it `UbuntuDisk`)

Thanks

Comment: I know you do not want to reinstall, but that is the better choice. Install & use rsync to copy configuration & data. Best to install & restore from your normal backup, as you still have install to add any missing data to backup. I did test install of kinetic, with ISO booted from grub, partitions already defined, install on NVMe drive was less than 5 min. Longest time was downloading apps from backed up list of manually added apps. Rsync data was very fast. see this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: Ok then. I guess I will just install Ubuntu on the new disk and move/reinstall the data stuff.

Comment: You were right it was pretty fast haha